# Archive Manager: An error occurred while loading the archive

Tags: filesystem, archive, compression, file-roller

I'm recently getting this error when trying to open a simple zip file using `file-roller`, aka Archive Manager.

I've unzip, unrar and 7zip installed already.

However, when I try decompressing the files using `unzip` in Terminal they work fine - except when using the Archive Manager GUI application.
The Archive Manager installed is of version 3.28.0.

This is the error message box I'm getting:

[image: Archive Manager error message screenshot]

How do I solve this?
Is there a way to check the logs pertaining to the Archive Manager to diagnose the issue?

Comment: Can you run file-roller in a terminal `file-roller -h archive.zip`?

Comment: Answering Boba Fit:
Same problem, I believe. file-roller -h (my zip) returns a box saying "Extraction not performed" with a close button.
a non-existent file gets
"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
I have purged and reinstalled file-roller.
7zip works OK. Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Is it one particular ZIP file or any ZIP file that doesn't work? Do any of the files inside the `.zip` have spaces, or *unusual* characters?

Comment: There is the similar bug reported on issue tracker of `Archive Manager`: [Error opening encrypted (password protected) ZIP archive](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/file-roller/-/issues/142)

Comment: This bug should be reported on issues tracker of `Archive Manager` [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/file-roller/-/issues). And probably it will be fixed with time.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably bug in [Archive Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Archive_Manager) which was previously called `File Roller`.
I encountered it when were trying to unzip password protected zip file under `Ubuntu 20.04` and `GNOME Archive Manager 3.36.3`.

I created the corresponding issue on issues tracker of `Archive Manager`:

- [Archive Manager: An error occurred while loading the archive.](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/file-roller/-/issues/194)